# Expressing element in basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I consider an orthonormal basis $v, w$ of a two dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For an element $u \in Span\{v,w \}$ with Euclidian length 1 how do I show that $u$ can be written $u=\sin(\theta) v + \cos(\theta) w$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $u$?

Comment: Hint: draw a triangle.

Comment: Don't you meant that $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $w$?

Comment: I have tried such and it is clearly true, but how can I show it otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic point $u \in Span\{v,w \}$ can be written as:

$$u = av+ bw,$$
where $a,b$ are two real numbers.

Recall that:

$$\|u\|^2 = (u,u),$$

where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the usual scalar product in Euclidean space. Then:

$$\|u\|^2 =(av+ bw,av+ bw) =a^2(v,v)+b^2(w,w)+2ab(u,w) =\\
= a^2 \|v\|^2 + b^2 \|w\|^2 + 2ab(u,w).$$

We know that $u,w$ is a orthonormal basis. So their norms are equal to $1$,

$$\|v\| = \|w\| = 1,$$

and since they are orthogonal, then:

$$(v,w) = 0.$$

Finally we get:

$$\|u\|^2 = a^2 + b^2.$$

Since the norm of $u$ is assumed to be $1$, then:

$$a^2 + b^2 = 1.$$

This means that must exists a number $\theta$, such that:

$$\begin{cases}
a = \cos(\theta)\\
b = \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}.$$